# An Bot To Join Online Class With Python Is Giving Invalid NameError

Tags: python, selenium, bots, microsoft-teams

This Is My Code:

```
#importing necessary modules for our program.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

#Fill In Your email and password in the CREDS dictionary.
CREDS = {"email" : "9714@sindhimodel.in", "password" : "DhruvSev2006"}

URL = "https://teams.microsoft.com"

def start_browser():
    #This Function Will Start Your Browser.
    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    chrome = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    chrome.get(URL)

    print("Browser Opened. \n")

    login()

def login():
    #This Function Will Login To Your Account, Using The CREDS dictionary.
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Logging In To Your Account. \n")

    EmailField = chrome.find_element_by_id("i0116")
    EmailField.send_keys(CRED['email'])

    next = chrome.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9")
    next.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    pswd = chrome.find_element_by_id("i0118")
    pswd.send_keys(CRED['password'])

    sign_in = chrome.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9")
    sign_in.click()
    time.sleep(2)

    web_app = chrome.find_element_by_class_name("use-app-lnk")
    web_app.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    print("Logged In To Your Account. \n")

def change_class():
    #This Function Is Related To My School And My Classes. You Can Delete It. :)
    print("Changing Format Of Classes. \n")

    clas = input("which Class Do You Want To Join: ")

    classes = [["maths", "english", "p/c", "biology", "csc", "social"], ["hindi"]]

    if clas in classes[0]:
        clas = "Class:9:All Subjects Except Hindi"
    elif clas in classes[1]:
        clas = "Class:9:Hindi"
    else:
        clas = ""
        raise KeyError("Class Not Found :(")
    return clas

def know_class():
    #This Will Ask The User For The Class, Which The User Wants To Join.
    clas = change_class()

    if clas == "Class:9:All Subjects Except Hindi":
        team = "9 General"
    elif clas == "Class:9:Hindi":
        team = "9 HINDI General"
    else:
        team = ""

def join_other_class():
    general_9 = chrome.find_element_by_title_name("ts-ongoing-call-header is-call-message")
    general_9.click()

start_browser()
know_class()
join_other_class()
```

Gives An Error In login() function (Line 20), When Called In start_browser() function (Line 79).

```
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

The Error Which Was Given ( When Running The Code In Command Prompt ( CMD ) In Windows ) Is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DHRUV\Desktop\New folder\o.py", line 79, in <module>
    start_browser()
  File "C:\Users\DHRUV\Desktop\New folder\o.py", line 20, in start_browser
    login()
  File "C:\Users\DHRUV\Desktop\New folder\o.py", line 27, in login
    EmailField = chrome.find_element_by_id("i0116")
NameError: name 'chrome' is not defined
```

Pls Help Me Out Here. I Have Defined `chrome` But It Stills Gives An Error.
Still The Code Isn't Finished But Still Want To Check If The Code Works Till Now.

*And Please Also Give Ways To Improve The Code. This Is Just Written In A Hurry. And Also I Am A Beginner.*

**Thanks In Advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chrome` is a local variable in `start_browser()`.

If you want to access it in your other method `login()`, you have several options:

1. Pass it as a parameter
2. Use a global variable (you may need to use the `global` keyword in your function if you're assigning it for the first time)
3. Instead of individual functions, write a class and make `chrome` an instance attribute, that way you can access it in all other instance methods with `self.chrome`

My personal preference would be option 3, but you may chose any option you want or even something totally different from my suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is specify the `chrome` as a global variable, you can do that in 2 different ways, first is just to put this code outside your function and let it be a variable that's available to all functions like this

```py
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
def start_browser():
    ...
```

Or by doing this

```py
def start_browser():
    #This Function Will Start Your Browser.
    PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    global chrome
    chrome = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    chrome.get(URL)

    print("Browser Opened. \n")

    login()
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_global_variables.asp) you can find out more about global variables